# jquery slider is affecting dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, slider, drop-down-menu

I am using jquery hoverintent on my dropdown menues and I also have a slider on the page I am working on. The fade in and out on the drowpdown is really crunchy.

You can see the working file here:
http://test.shared-vision.net/DMP/index.html

When I take the slide off I have no problems with the dropdown, I have one other slider (slidesjs) with the same result. 
Example here: http://test.shared-vision.net/DMP/index_test_slider.html

Any advice or assistance as to what I can do to fix this is appreciated.

Thanks.
-Ann

Comment: just noticed you are getting an error: fbg is not defined fbg.hideFOUT('asap', 400);  index.html line:25

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I had moved the foutbgone.js. but still getting same effect with the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using hoverintent wrong. I attached it to the li ul and not just the li.
-Ann K